# Magento 2 Rest API getting "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again on some installations but works in postman

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have a small php script that fetch some product information from the Magento 2 Rest API.

The problem I am facing is that it works fine for some Magento 2 shops, but not others. For some shops I get

*"The signature is invalid. Verify and try again."*

But if I use the same credentials in Postman I get:

[image]

This is the script getting the products from Magento 2

```
$url = $_GET["url"]; 
$apiUrl = $url . 'rest/V1/products';
$consumerKey = $_GET["consumerKey"]; 
$consumerSecret = $_GET["consumerSecret"]; 
$accessToken = $_GET["accessToken"]; 
$accessTokenSecret = $_GET["accessTokenSecret"]; 
$searchurl = $apiUrl;
$method = 'GET';

function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{
    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);
    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($data, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', [$method, $url, $data]);
    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}


$search = [
    'searchCriteria[pageSize]' => 2,
    'searchCriteria[currentPage]' => 1,
];
ksort($search);
$data = array_merge([
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce' => md5(uniqid(rand(), true)),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_token' => $accessToken,
    'oauth_version' => '1.0',
],$search);

$data['oauth_signature'] = sign($method, $searchurl, $data, $consumerSecret, $accessTokenSecret);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $searchurl . '?' . http_build_query($search),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: OAuth ' . http_build_query($data, '', ',')
    ]
]);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Can anyone give me a clue as to why this happens?

Comment: Please share more details like which method you have used in postman and all, it's hard to assume it from your screenshot, provide proper details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a resource permissions problem, consider rechecking the permissions on the integration.